# bash split one line file into more lines based on a condition

Tags: json, bash, unix, awk, split

Hi I have a json file made of lines in which every line contains something similar:

```
[{“user1”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7},{“user2”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7},{“user3”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7}]
```

(it is all in the same line)

I would like to create a file in which every line is like that(a user per line):

```
{“user1”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7}
{“user2”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7}
{“user3”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you aware that the result you want contains more opening than closing brackets?

Comment: now should be ok. Values are not important. It is just a re-formatting  issue.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, replaces `,{` with a newline and a `,{` and gets a substring from the second to second to last character.

```
awk '{ gsub(",{","\n{"); {print substr($0, 2, length($0) - 2)} }' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit for new version of question input:

```
sed -e 's/^\[//' -e 's/]$/}/' -e 's/,{/}\n{/g'
```

It's a little less pretty (although you only really need the last bit - the first two `s/`s are just to tidy the opening/closing `[,]`s

```
$ echo '[{“user1”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7},{“user2”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7},{“user3”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7}]' | sed -e 's/^\[//' -e 's/]$/}/' -e 's/,{/}\n{/g'
{“user1”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7}}
{“user2”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7}}
{“user3”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7}}
```

Comment: If a `value` is sth like `{"a":"b", "c":"d"}` this will produce unexpected results.

Comment: same in awk `awk '{ gsub("},","}\n[") ;print}' file`

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume "key7" is always the same?

Comment: the values doesn't matter. All I want is to format the document in the right way. Each line should be a different user

Comment: Whether the keys are (or are not) the same each time is important as if they are then it potentially gives an additional item to key off off for the split detection, although unless your keys/values have weird things in them, I don't think it will be needed (on reflection).

Comment: I got the same output..maybe my question is still not clear. I just want on each line a different user.. the input has in one line different users, and with your command it doesn't change

Comment: *frowns* it works for me on the sample data you supplied - does it work for you on the sample data? (wondering if it is a weird sed version issue).

Comment: This adds double brackets on the end, there should only be one ? All on separate line for me though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the input is JSON (or compatible), although you did not state concrete values for the parts you just named `value`.  I assumed a plain `42` for each of these `value`s and then used a proper JSON parsing to achieve what you wanted.  The parser I chose was the Python JSON library, but others will work as well of course.

I took the liberty to fix the input.  There were several closing braces missing.

The result is not quite the format you asked for but because what you asked for is syntactically nonsense because of the missing closing brackets (I commented on your question about this), I assume the output format is not as fixed.  And anyway, the complex part is the proper parsing; the output then is a simple thing.

```
echo '[{"key1":{"key2":"value","key2":[{"key3":42,"key4":"value"}],"key5":42}},{"key1":{"key2":"value","key2":[{"key3":42,"key4":"value"}],"key5":42}},{"key1":{"key2":"value","key2":[{"key3":42,"key4":"value"}],"key5":42}},{"key1":{"key2":"value","key2":[{"key3":42,"key4":"value"}],"key5":42}}]' \
  | python -c 'import json, sys; v=json.load(sys.stdin); print "\n".join(str(x) for x in v)'
```

Comment: sorry I changed the question, would you like to check now?

Answer (score 0):

For the given input, this will do:

```
sed -re 's/(\{"key1)/\n\1/g' | sed -re '/^\[/ d'
```

But as Alfe said you have more opening brackets than closing brackets. Also a json parser would be a better answer.

Comment: sorry I changed the question a bit, I realized the mistakes..hope you can check it..

Comment: I will add a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the input to `perl -ple 's|({“user)|\n$1|g' |sed -re 's/^\[|\]$//g' | sed -re '/^$/ d'`:

```
 echo '[{“user1”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7},{“user2”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7},{“user3”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7}]' | perl -ple 's|({“user)|\n$1|g' |sed -re 's/^\[|\]$//g' | sed -re '/^$/ d'
{“user1”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7},
{“user2”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7},
{“user3”:{“key1”:”value”,”key2”:”value2”,”key3”:[{“key4”:”value4”,”key5”:”value5”}],”key6”:”value6”},”key7”:”value7}
```

PS. A json parser would still be a better answer :)